# laravel public folder access issue

Tags: php, css, laravel, .htaccess, resources

I'm working on a web app with Laravel, and i've a strange behavior around how to show it from my server. 
I choose the simplest way to show it right now, `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

All now is accessible through links like:

```
http://myip/urbelog_backend/public/index.php/
http://myip/urbelog_backend/public/index.php/login
....
```

or for the api part things like:

```
http://myip/urbelog_backend/public/index.php/api/signMeUp
```

Def isn't the cleanest way but for now works and it's enough! The I add some views and some resources like images in the public folder, but all is not accesible, even css seem to be not available  -but there are-

The problem that i've spotted is inside in how the link of resources are build, for example the instruction:

```
<img src="{{ URL::to('/images') }}/urbelog_l.jpg">
```

give me back the url:

```
http://myip/urbelog_backend/public/index.php/images/urbelog_l.jpg
```

instead of

```
http://myip/urbelog_backend/public/images/urbelog_l.jpg
```

thats work!

how can I solve this mess?
cheers

Comment: Take the .htaccess to the root folder and make it point to public/index.php.

Comment: You've exposed your environment variables publicly. The internet has your application key and database credentials. Change them and secure your stuff.

Comment: @sisve wich enviroment variable sorry? myip isnt my actual ip...

Comment: @sisve ok seen the problem ill try to secure all

Comment: @sisve now that finally is all secure i solved all my problems...it was a rewrite rule under apache2.conf not setted!